# Hotjar returns 413 Request Entity Too Large

Tags: http-status-code-413, localtunnel, hotjar

I'm using [react-use-hotjar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-use-hotjar) and I can see from adding logging call backs that hotjar is successfully initialising with the correct site id and `identifyHotjar` calls are working also. However, no recordings are showing up in the hotjar dashboard.

In the network tab I can see;

`POST https://ws3.hotjar.com/api/v2/sites/[my-site-id]/recordings/content => 413 Request Entity Too Large`

this request does have the following header:  `Content-Length: 16748416`

which admittedly does seem large - but if I'm uploading video to hotjar I'm kind of expecting that to be reasonably large - so wouldn't this end point be configured to accept large payloads?

I can also see another failing request;

`POST https://in.hotjar.com/api/v1/sites/[my-site-id]/deferred-page-content/[some-other-id] => 413`

which also has this header: `content-length: 16331099` - again pretty big.

Further background - I am running this site on my localhost and exposing it via [local tunnel](https://github.com/localtunnel/localtunnel) - I'm not sure if that make a difference

Has anyone come across this? I've googled it but I can't find anyone else talking about a 413 from hotjar.

Comment: I also faced the same issue. In my case, it is fixed when i deploy to cloud server with https  (eg. https://my-website.com)